# MYSQL PHP while loop, do something if there aren't a given amount of rows returned

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, return, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do something like this. Basically what I want to do (in a simple example) would be query the database and return the 3 rows, however if there aren't 3 rows, say there are 0, 1, or 2, then I want to put other data in place of the missing rows.

Say my query returns 2 rows. Then there should be 1 list element returned with other data.

Something like this:
http://i42.tinypic.com/30xhi1f.png

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 3");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  print "<li>".$row['post']."</li>";
}
//(this is just to give an idea of what i would likkeee to be able to do
else
{
  print "<li>Add something here</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways I can think of, get the row count with mysql_num_rows, prime an array with three values and replace them as you loop the result set, or count down from three as your work, and finish the count with a second loop, like this:

```
$result = db_query($query);
$addRows = 3;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result){
    $addRows--;
    // do your stuff
}
while ($addRows-- > 0) {
    // do your replacement stuff
}
```

Comment: That actually works perfectly, thanks. 
I never know you could subtract using -- either, that's new to me

Answer (score 3):

You can get the number of items in the resultset with [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php). Just build the difference to find out how many items are "missing".

Answer (score 1):

If you dont find a row, Add extra information accordingly.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if($row){
        print "<li>".$row['post']."</li>";
    }
    //(this is just to give an idea of what i would likkeee to be able to do
    else{
        print "<li>Add something here</li>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you store the rows in an array or somesuch, you can simply do some padding with a `while` loop (depending how you generate the other data):

```
while (count($resultList) < 3) {
    // add another row
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I put that in an example as I have just put in my question?

Comment: In that case you have to replace the `count($resultList)` in my code with a call to `mysql_num_rows($query)`, and place it in the `else` part of your code.